# Inter vlan routing not working

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, layer3, hp-procurve

Apologies if any details not clear as I'm not a network expert.

I have a Procurve 3500yl layer-3 switch. I am trying to make two VLANs and get a PC in one VLAN to connect to the other VLAN.

Below is the running configuration from the switch:

```
Running configuration:

; J8692A Configuration Editor; Created on release #K.14.41

hostname "ProCurve Switch 3500yl-24G"

module 1 type J86xxA

ip routing

vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   untagged 9-24
   no untagged 1-8
   no ip address
   exit

vlan 20
   name "local"
   untagged 5-8
   ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
   exit

vlan 10
   name "operator"
   untagged 2-4
   ip address 10.11.156.31 255.255.255.0
   tagged 1
   exit

ip route 10.11.156.0 255.255.255.0 vlan 10
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 vlan 20
snmp-server community "public" unrestricted
```

I am trying to get PC (IP address: `192.168.1.2`) to ping IP address `10.11.156.1` which is another router connected to VLAN 10.

I can ping `10.11.156.31` which is the VLAN address, but I can't ping `10.11.156.1`. Do you have any idea what is the problem here?

Comment: Just because 1.2 knows how to get a packet to 156.1 does not mean 156.1 knows how to get back to 1.2.

Comment: @RickyBeam but they are directly connect networks. shouldn't they see each other normally?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `ip route` lines should be redundant as the subnets are directly attached. Remove the lines from config and verify with `show ip route`.

You need to make sure that

1. the `10.11.156.1` host has a default route to `10.11.156.31` (or specific route to `192.168.1.0/24`).
2. connectivity between `10.11.156.1` and `10.11.156.31` is established. Can you ping either way?

Comment: I removed the ip route lines but still the issue.

Comment: also ip 10.11.156.1 and ip 10.11.156.31 can bing each other normally

Comment: See 1. - can you ping `192.168.1.1` from `10.11.156.1`??

Comment: No I can't do that. Do you know why or what shall be done ?

Comment: Yet again, does `10.11.156.1` have a route to `192.168.1.0/24`, default or specific??

Answer (score 2):

Has your PC (192,168.1.2/24) got the vlan interface as it's default gateway? 192.168.1.1?

Also the router on VLAN10 should have a route for 192.168.1.1/24 pointing to 10.11.156.31. I'm sure this is a simple routing issue.